# C++, templated template specification

Tags: c++, templates, specifications

I have a template which doesn't implement two methods.

I want to use only classes which are specifications of the template, for those I supply a specification.

Example:

```
template<class T> class Temp
{
  void Method1();
};

Temp<int>::method1() {...}
```

Now I want to supply a template type for specification, like

```
template<class General> void Temp<General> method1() {...}
```

And I will specify which types are the `General`.

How can I do it with the C++ syntax?

Comment: Sent from mobile btw...sorry if i have some typos

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to provide a bunch of specializations for a list of known types. To accomplish that, you could use SFINAE, (e.g. `std::enable_if`) and some template meta programming.

To give you an idea:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class... Candidates>
struct is_one_of;

/* alternative 1 - too complicated
template <class T, class Head, class... Tail>
struct is_one_of<T, Head, Tail...> 
  : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T, Head>::value || is_one_of<T, Tail...>::value>
{}; */

/* better alternative - thanks, Dan */
template <class T, class Head, class... Tail>
struct is_one_of<T, Head, Tail...> : is_one_of<T, Tail...> {}

template <class T, class... Tail>
struct is_one_of<T, T, Tail...> : std::true_type {}

/* needed for both alternatives */
template <class T>
struct is_one_of<T> : std::false_type {};
```

Now `enable_if` you specializations depending on `is_one_of<T, ?your-list-of-General-types-here?>`

Comment: Or,

    template <class T, class Head, class... Tail>
    struct is_one_of<T, Head, Tail...> : is_one_of<T, Tail...>
    {};

    template <class T, class... Tail>
    struct is_one_of<T, T, Tail...> : std::true_type
    {};